# How to Code an .htaccess Redirect Without Changing the Address Bar

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hiho,

I would like redirect: 
http://ads.polishexpress.co.uk/en
to
http://ogloszenia.polishexpress.co.uk/en
without change adress bar.

My attempt is displayed in the code below:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    # Use PHP5.4 as default
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ads\.polishexpress\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ads\.polishexpress\.co\.uk\/en$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/ogloszenia\.polishexpress\.co\.uk\/en" [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ads\.polishexpress\.co\.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ogloszenia.polishexpress.co.uk/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: I put ads.polishexpress.co.uk [enter]
and i see ogloszenia.polishexpress.co.uk in adress bar :(

Comment: I see. You want a proxy, in that case change [r=301,nc] to  [P,L]

Comment: Internal Server Error, look this adress: http://ads.polishexpress.co.uk ; htaccess: 
## Default .htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ads\.polishexpress\.co\.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ogloszenia.polishexpress.co.uk/$1 [P, L]

Comment: Could be a problem with mod_proxy. Did you check that it's loaded?.